# Slick JS - How to reload content with ajax data

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have data in `slick js slider`

I want to `reload` another data and `reinit` slick with new data.

I tried this :

Here is the function:

```
function getSliderSettings(){
        return {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            rows: 2,
            slidesPerRow: 3,
            centerMode: false,
            arrows: false,
            dots: true,
            infinite: false,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1100,
                    settings: {
                        slidesPerRow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

code for re-init slider

```
var data = "<div>a</div><div>b</div>";
$("#categorySlider-13").slick('reinit');
$("#categorySlider-13").html(data);
$("#categorySlider-13").slick(getSliderSettings());
```

But it doesnt work !

If You know another js plugin carousel working with ajax call, can you tell it to me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$("#categorySlider-13").slick('unslick')` before assigning new data then init again.

Also, it advised to use  `.not('.slick-initialized')`, so you done accidentally initialize slider more than once [See here for more](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1953#issuecomment-220598733])

```js
function getSliderSettings(){
        return {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            rows: 2,
            slidesPerRow: 3,
            centerMode: false,
            arrows: false,
            dots: true,
            infinite: false,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1100,
                    settings: {
                        slidesPerRow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
$("#categorySlider-13").slick(getSliderSettings());

$('#btn1').on('click',function(){

var data = "<div>A</div><div>B</div><div>C</div><div>D</div><div>E</div>";
$("#categorySlider-13").slick('unslick')
$("#categorySlider-13").html(data);
$("#categorySlider-13").not('.slick-initialized').slick(getSliderSettings());
});
```

```css
$c1: #3a8999;
$c2: #e84a69;

.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background:  #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background:  #e84a69;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js"></script>

<section id ="categorySlider-13" class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>

<button id="btn1" >
Click me!!
</button>
```